# Extracting regions of text from list of strings with Haskell

Tags: regex, haskell

I require to extract information from a list of strings (obtained from file) and return the result as a list of matched lines. The function prototype I made is as follows:

```
extractRegions :: [String] -> [String]
extractRegions list = undefined -- not sure about definition
```

I understand that the `Text.Regex.Posix` library is recommended for doing this, but I can't find any information on using it within a Haskell file context, and the API library is confusing. I would like to extract certain regions that begin with some word and end in another, e.g. begins with "Start" and ends with "Finish", with text in-between that is also matched with this regular expression.

How should I address this simple idea in Haskell?

Many thanks

Comment: try `Parsec`, for example http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Parsec

Comment: What do you mean by "In a file context"? A list of strings is a list of strings; they don't become harder or easier to analyse for having come from a file.

Comment: @itsbruce I mean I haven't found any examples using regular expressions within functions in Haskell source files - they use ghci prelude.

Comment: @user1272525 code in GHCi looks more or less identical to what you'd type into your `.hs` file; see any haskell book for details. As for your actual question it's hard to know what you're asking. Can you provide some combination of 1) what you've tried (a type signature represents about the bare minimum of thought here) 2) examples of expected input and output 3) what in particular you find confusing about the API, or the examples you've looked at.

Comment: Have you seen the [chapter 8 of Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/efficient-file-processing-regular-expressions-and-file-name-matching.html)? It's exclusively about regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

The [regex-compat](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-compat-0.95.1/docs/Text-Regex.html) package is significantly easier to start with. `Text.Regex.Posix` may be the weapon you turn to eventually, but it has a more confusing interface due to its very general overloading of `(=~)`.

Above that, the "Haskelly" way to handle this kind of problem is to create a type that represents the information in each line of your argument to `extractRegions` (let's call it `Line` for argument's sake) and then create a parser

```
data Line   = Line   { ..., region :: Region, ... }
data Region = Region { ... }

parseLine :: String -> Maybe Line
```

using a library like `Parsec` or `Attoparsec`. From there, we can extract the information we need from the `Region` type very easily by using the `region` record accessor function.

```
map record :: [Line] -> [Region]
```

and then combine these pieces to get the complete picture

```
extractRegions :: [String] -> [Region]
extractRegions input = case sequence (map parseLine input) of
  Nothing    -> error "One of our line parses failed!"
  Just lines -> map record lines
```

Comment: Do you really mean `region = Region` in your `Line`-type?

Comment: No, typo on my part. I'm defining the type so I use `region :: Region` to state the type of that slot in the record.